# How to update based on existing data in mongo

Tags: mongodb

Sort of a mongo noob, and I have a feeling I am tackling this problem from the wrong direction.

I have about a 7 million document collection. Each document has two fields that I want to *modify* (not replace), basically they are big strings that have `\\n`, and I want to replace those with `\n`.

I spent about an hour trying to find a way to "back reference" the object returned by the query, which totally doesn't exist. What is the best approach for something like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to query for all the documents and update them one by one.  If you do it in JavaScript, it would be something like:

```
mydb = db.getSisterDB("whateverDBYoureUsing");
var cursor = mydb.foo.find();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    var x = cursor.next();

    /* replace \\n with \n in x's strings ... */

    db.foo.update({_id : x._id}, x);
}
```

You can copy this into a .js file (say, replace.js), change the db and collection names, and run it as a script from the shell:

```
mongo replace.js
```

Comment: pretty much what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is doing an upsert http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-UpsertswithModifiers

Comment: @Thilo: actually it is pretty same stuff as Kristina suggested. Less elaborated answer, but same. So I don't get, why Markus got "-2" for it.